# Swift 4 generics with struct

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to use `generics` with `Codable` protocol, but I'm getting an error.

`Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([T.Type], from: Data)`

```
static func getRequest<T>(model: T.Type, url: String, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil, headers: [String: String]? = nil, data: @escaping (Any?, Any?, Error?) -> ()) -> Alamofire.DataRequest {

     return Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate(contentType: [RequestHelper.HeaderKeys.contentTypeJson])
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let responseData = response.data!
                do {
                    print(model)
                    print(T.self)
                    let decodable = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: responseData)
                    data(response.response?.allHeaderFields, decodable, nil)
                } catch let error {
                    data(nil, nil, error)
                }
            case .failure(let requestError):
                data(nil, nil, requestError)
                print(requestError)
            }
    }
}
```

I need pass my struct model to this method

How can I fix this? Does anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decode()` can only take a type that is `Decodable`. You need to specify that in your method signature. Either add `where T: Decodable` at the end of `getRequest`'s declaration or just put `<T: Decodable>` inside the brackets to restrict T to decodable types only, and then you should be able to pass your parameter to `decode()`.

EDIT: Looking at your code, there's another error:

```
let decodable = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: responseData)
```

Instead of `[model].self`, you need to pass `[T].self`. Otherwise you're passing an array of types rather than the type *of* an array.

Comment: I have another error `'Decodable' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`

Comment: @VictorMendes Can you please post the exact line that's causing the error?

Comment: @VictorMendes May have found your problem. See edited answer.